# continue/pass для list comprehension

Tags: python

Что можно записать вместо None что бы  if ничего не добавляло?Я хочу получить число но именно в таком виде, я знаю что можно было бы написать if not x.isalpha, но мне интересно если тут какая то замена continue/pass?

```
r = "6015ekx"
number = [ None if x.isalpha() else x for x  in r ]
```

Comment: [x for x  in r  if (и тут условие)]

Comment: Но зачем, если можно написать if not x.isalpha?

Comment: @andreymal интересно

Answer (score 0):

Вообще чисто для фильтрации данных придумана отдельная функция `filter`, хотя её результат ещё нужно потом превратить в список. Например, если достаточно было бы условия `isdigit`, то можно было бы записать коротко:

```py
r = "6015ekx"
number = list(filter(str.isdigit, r))
```

Но если нужно фильтровать именно по `not isalpha`, то будет чуть длиннее, через `lambda`:

```py
r = "6015ekx"
number = list(filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), r))
```

Но так уже получается не короче, чем если использовать *списковое сокращение* с условием, то есть то, что вы не хотите использовать.